# Convert Double Value ToString()

Tags: c#

May be I'm asking silly question but I don't understand why this doesn't give me the output I expect (*i.e* `2.5`):

```
double x = 5/2;
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vxJcFA)

Comment: Integer division. `5/2 == 2`.Try `double x = 5.0/2`

Comment: Tnx @AlexD! and the answer helped me understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`5 / 2` performs [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) *no matter* which type you assign it. It always disregards fractional part.

You need to use floating-point division instead.

```
double x = 5.0 / 2;
double x = 5 / 2.0;
double x = 5.0 / 2.0;
```

From [`/` Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx)

> When you divide two integers, the result is **always** an integer. For
>   example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2.

From C# Specification part [$7.7.2 Division operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), there 3 types of division;

- Integer division
- Floating-point division
- Decimal division

And from the relevant part in integer division;

> The division rounds the result towards zero, and the absolute value of
>   the result is the largest possible integer that is less than the
>   absolute value of the quotient of the two operands. The result is zero
>   or positive when the two operands have the same sign and zero or
>   negative when the two operands have opposite signs.